# Mongo::ReplSetConnection authenticate fail

Tags: ruby, mongodb, authentication

This is the simple script.

```
require 'mongo'
database=Mongo::ReplSetConnection.new(["database1:9900", "database2:9900","database3:9900"]).db("project")
database.authenticate("user","passwd")
```

I got the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `pools' for # <Mongo::ReplSetConnection:0x0000000441e610>
from /home/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myrails3/gems/mongo-1.7.0/lib/mongo/repl_set_connection.rb:309:in `authenticate_pools'
```

Has anyone encountered such problem before? Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The following method works for me. But I don't know why.

```
con=Mongo::ReplSetConnection.new(["host1:14000", "host2:14000", "host3:14000"])
con.add_auth("databasename","user","passwd")
con.apply_saved_authentication()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the following bugfix:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/pull/112

If you change that code on your driver it will work.

Comment: Its fixed now on release 1.8.0